# MongoDB: querying arrays for specific element sequences

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

## Context:

We use Mongo to persist session information on users visiting websites of our clients. Most of which is simply session metadata (origin time, browser, os, country etc. etc.).

One of those fields is an inconspicuous 'pages' array. Which consists of a sequence of websites ordered by when they were visited by the user. Simple enough. However now we find ourselves in a pressing need to filter them by the order they occur in the array relative to EACH OTHER, and not simply IF they occur in the array.

## Example:

Consider the following pages array:

```
    [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" ]
```

Is there any way in MongoDB to query for say: "retrieve every document from db.sessions.pages where B is followed directly by C AND D is followed directly or indirectly by G AND the entire sequence ends with H?

To reiterate - this example should pass the above query as well:

```
    [ "D", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "H" ]
```

Taking into consideration that we have hundreds of thousands of documents per client... Is the effect we want to achieve possible in any way? I understand that if it is - it would likely require some form of aggregation. Or did we simply shoot ourselves completely in the foot by choosing Mongo?

Comment: What do you mean by *D is followed directly or indirectly by G*? What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: We are using Mongo 3.2 on production.

The "direct"/"indirect" functionality would be nice to have, but it isn't necessary for our scenario. By "element B being directly followed by element G" I mean that in the array representing the sequence of websites there is at least one such sub-sequence that if B is on the n-th position, then G is on the n+1. By "element B being indirectly followed by element G" I mean that there is at least one such sub-sequence that if B is on the n-th position, then G is on the n+k.

Again this specific functionality is not crucial, everything else is though ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex task, and even in SQL when using `CTE` it is not easy as it looks.

imho this could be done by custom js

```
var requiredSequence = [a, b]
var requiredElement = 'g'
    db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
        var arrayLenght = doc.array.lenght;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLenght - 1; i++) {
            if (doc.array[i] === requiredSequence[0] && doc.array[i + 1] === requiredSequence[1]) {
                if (doc.array.indexOf(requiredElement) > -1) {
                    // we have all criteria meet
                    printjson(doc);
                    break;
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: as I'm in bed ☺ I have some ideas how to improve array search algorithm when the idea is not iteration but first search for index position and then have match for n+1...